# How can i find memory location from apple crash report? from where my app is crash.?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

my app is rejected from ap store and the  reason is.

```
    2.1: Apps that crash will be rejected 
We found that your app crashed on iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.5
```

and i have also tested this app in iPhone 4 (ios 4.3.5) and my app not crash.
but my app rejected from app store due to crash.
and i also found many solution from stack overflow but i am not getting memory location from where my app going to be crash.
please help me t find that. i am not getting how to do that.
my crash report is:

```
Incident Identifier: 47BDC9E2-6189-4A87-80CE-ED62D167C9BE
CrashReporter Key:   41f8ec19572cb609293b644a709bc43a95f4665b
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         incognito [901]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/9B344675-F3FF-4C26-B76D-53F94F653323/incognito.app/incognito
Identifier:      incognito
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-08-10 11:37:27.599 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f46a1c 0x33f35000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f803b4 0x33f4d000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f78bf8 0x33f4d000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33039a64 0x32ff5000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x334f906c 0x334f3000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33037e36 0x32ff5000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33037e8a 0x32ff5000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33037f5a 0x32ff5000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x334f7c84 0x334f3000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x362a21b8 0x36200000 + 663992
10  CoreFoundation                  0x362a1642 0x36200000 + 661058
11  CoreFoundation                  0x36218178 0x36200000 + 98680
12  APPNAME                         0x0000f5da 0x1000 + 58842
13  Foundation                      0x3465a2ee 0x34648000 + 74478
14  Foundation                      0x3465a270 0x34648000 + 74352
15  CFNetwork                       0x3586240a 0x35853000 + 62474
16  CFNetwork                       0x35856f3e 0x35853000 + 16190
17  CFNetwork                       0x35856e30 0x35853000 + 15920
18  CFNetwork                       0x35856de2 0x35853000 + 15842
19  CFNetwork                       0x35856d54 0x35853000 + 15700
20  CFNetwork                       0x35856cd2 0x35853000 + 15570
21  CoreFoundation                  0x36275a72 0x36200000 + 481906
22  CoreFoundation                  0x36277758 0x36200000 + 489304
23  CoreFoundation                  0x362784e4 0x36200000 + 492772
24  CoreFoundation                  0x36208ebc 0x36200000 + 36540
25  CoreFoundation                  0x36208dc4 0x36200000 + 36292
26  GraphicsServices                0x359c2418 0x359be000 + 17432
27  GraphicsServices                0x359c24c4 0x359be000 + 17604
28  UIKit                           0x350b2d62 0x35084000 + 191842
29  UIKit                           0x350b0800 0x35084000 + 182272
30  APPNAME                         0x000028ba 0x1000 + 6330
31  APPNAME                         0x00002884 0x1000 + 6276

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f47fbc 0x33f35000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33118032 0x33112000 + 24626
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3311903a 0x33112000 + 28730
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x331185ea 0x33112000 + 26090
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f8158a 0x33f4d000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bbc 0x33f4d000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f44c00 0x33f35000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f44758 0x33f35000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x362762b8 0x36200000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36278562 0x36200000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36208ebc 0x36200000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36208dc4 0x36200000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x359d127e 0x359cb000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f8030a 0x33f4d000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bb4 0x33f4d000 + 215988

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f48ed0 0x33f35000 + 81616
1   CFNetwork                       0x35866182 0x35853000 + 78210
2   CFNetwork                       0x358d8488 0x35853000 + 545928
3   CFNetwork                       0x358b248c 0x35853000 + 390284
4   CFNetwork                       0x358b2508 0x35853000 + 390408
5   Security                        0x33910790 0x3390a000 + 26512
6   Security                        0x339101fe 0x3390a000 + 25086
7   Security                        0x339104f6 0x3390a000 + 25846
8   CFNetwork                       0x358b2912 0x35853000 + 391442
9   CFNetwork                       0x35865fba 0x35853000 + 77754
10  CFNetwork                       0x35865e26 0x35853000 + 77350
11  CFNetwork                       0x35865e04 0x35853000 + 77316
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3621cb6c 0x36200000 + 117612
13  CFNetwork                       0x35865a88 0x35853000 + 76424
14  CFNetwork                       0x3585e5e0 0x35853000 + 46560
15  CFNetwork                       0x3586561a 0x35853000 + 75290
16  CFNetwork                       0x358654ec 0x35853000 + 74988
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3621da1a 0x36200000 + 121370
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3621d9b6 0x36200000 + 121270
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3621d8aa 0x36200000 + 121002
20  CoreFoundation                  0x36223ca4 0x36200000 + 146596
21  CFNetwork                       0x358d7c34 0x35853000 + 543796
22  CFNetwork                       0x358653f4 0x35853000 + 74740
23  CFNetwork                       0x35865376 0x35853000 + 74614
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3627a3d2 0x36200000 + 500690
25  CoreFoundation                  0x3627b4a2 0x36200000 + 504994
26  CoreFoundation                  0x36275a72 0x36200000 + 481906
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3627769c 0x36200000 + 489116
28  CoreFoundation                  0x362784e4 0x36200000 + 492772
29  CoreFoundation                  0x36208ebc 0x36200000 + 36540
30  CoreFoundation                  0x36208dc4 0x36200000 + 36292
31  Foundation                      0x346727f6 0x34648000 + 174070
32  Foundation                      0x34665382 0x34648000 + 119682
33  Foundation                      0x346d75c6 0x34648000 + 587206
34  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f8030a 0x33f4d000 + 209674
35  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bb4 0x33f4d000 + 215988

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f46c60 0x33f35000 + 72800
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3627b8f2 0x36200000 + 506098
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f8030a 0x33f4d000 + 209674
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bb4 0x33f4d000 + 215988

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f44c00 0x33f35000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f44758 0x33f35000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x362762b8 0x36200000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36278562 0x36200000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36208ebc 0x36200000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3624b6d2 0x36200000 + 308946
6   incognito                       0x0002b350 0x1000 + 172880
7   Foundation                      0x34665382 0x34648000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x346d75c6 0x34648000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f8030a 0x33f4d000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bb4 0x33f4d000 + 215988

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f473ec 0x33f35000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f816d8 0x33f4d000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bbc 0x33f4d000 + 215996

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f473ec 0x33f35000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f816d8 0x33f4d000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bbc 0x33f4d000 + 215996

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f473ec 0x33f35000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f816d8 0x33f4d000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bbc 0x33f4d000 + 215996

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33f473ec 0x33f35000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f816d8 0x33f4d000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33f81bbc 0x33f4d000 + 215996

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3e7c248c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x001a197c      r7: 0x2fdfe714
    r8: 0x3537e778    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x3eeb9b98     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe708      lr: 0x33f803bb      pc: 0x33f46a1c
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: How did you Symbolicate? , I mean what are the steps to follow cause I am a bit confused with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) and [this](https://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html#fnr2-2011-05-12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooh yeah. You need to "Symbolicate" the crash logs to make sense out of it. Check these links.

http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html

http://www.buildingiphoneapps.com/2011/03/processing-users-crash-logs-when.html

http://www.eigo.co.uk/Deciphering-iPhone-Crash-Logs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Product>Profile in your Xcode and then check allocations,zombies, memory leaks, etc to see where exactly the crash happens. The reason for the crash might be memory over-allocation. The profiler will tell you if that is the case.