# Not Able to read Xcode crash log

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I received a crash in my app I released on App Store few days ago. I got the crash report in Xcode 8.3 but am not able to debug it. Can somebody help going through the report?.
I have attached a screenshot of the crash report from inside Xcode.

[image: crash log]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode)

Comment: there is nothing to read in this report. Because there are addresses, not the exact crash causing function names.

Comment: so how i can identify which function is causing the problem?

Comment: Have a look at my answer and try doing that! let me know if it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can Symbolicate the Crash report with a lot of methods.
First, you need to save the .app file which caused the crash. And .crash file and the `dSYM` file. You can download the dSYM from Organiser.

Symbolicate crash report by doing this:

Put .app, .crash and `dSYM` files in on folder then go to that folder in terminal then write the below line :

> xcrun atos -o MyApp.app/MyApp -arch armv7 -l 0xb7000 -f
>   WhateverTherNameIs.crash

REFERENCES:

[How to symbolicate crash log with Xcode 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804611/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-with-xcode-7)

[How can I find memory location from apple crash report? from where my app is crash.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023111/how-can-i-find-memory-location-from-apple-crash-report-from-where-my-app-is-cra)

[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

[New XCode Crash Organizer Does Not Symbolicate .xccrashpoint Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131434/new-xcode-crash-organizer-does-not-symbolicate-xccrashpoint-files)

[Atos cannot get symbols from dSYM of archived application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675863/atos-cannot-get-symbols-from-dsym-of-archived-application)

Comment: i used the command "xcrun atos -o MyApp.app/MyApp -arch armv7 -l 0xb7000 -f WhateverTherNameIs.crash" in the terminal and it is giving me lots of data as text but still i am not able to figure out the problem

Comment: yes, in that data you have to find the function that is causing the problem. Try to find other functions and particular Thread with that.

Comment: Do your `viewController`s have other references which you have deleted previously?

Comment: How to get .crash file if my crashes are reported to fabric.io?

Answer (score 0):

1) create a new folder ,lets say "Universe" , to hold the stuff.

2) use the Go to Folder utility from Finder . Use the path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/

Find "symbolicatecrash" file and you can manually copy and paste this file to your Universe folder

3) Place your crash and Archive of your app in your folder ( Archive will hold all the dysm files. Alternatively you can place all your dYsm files )

4) CD to your "Universe" folder directory . Now run this command export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

5)run the symbolicate command on your crash

./symbolicatecrash myCrash.crash > SymbolicatedM.crash

Voila!! you have your symbolicated crash log.

PS : The added advantage of this is that the above setup is a one time setup and is reusable .All that is required is just replace your crash file and dysm file , then just repeat step 5 each time you want a new crash symbolicated. Bye bye complicated commands!